# Java Error- cannot find symbol- Variable is

Tags: java, variables, input, find, symbols

I tried to make a "shortcut" to the print, println, and the scanner. So I created a different class, and that's what it had in it:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShortCutClass {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void p (String text){
        System.out.print (text);
    }
    public void pl (String text){
        System.out.println (text);
    }
    public String is (){
        String a= input.nextLine();
        return a;
    }
    public double id (){
        double b= input.nextDouble();
        return b;
    }
    public int ii (){
        int c= input.nextInt();
        return c;
    }
}
```

So, I tried to check if it works- using this:

```
import java.util.*;
class ShortcutTest{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ShortCutClass scc = new ShortCutClass();
        scc.pl("So ummmm... How ya doin?");
        scc.p("Connected1 ");
        scc.p("Connected2 ");
        String a=scc.is;
        double b=scc.id;
        int c=scc.ii;
        scc.pl (a);
        scc.pl (b);
        scc.pl (c);        
    }
}
```

and it gives me the following Error:
"cannot find symbol- variable is

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

*** Edit:

I fixed it, and ran into another problem...
I can not print out b or c because the print I wrote requires a String, and b and c can only be double and int, so that won't work.
is there any way of changing the print (scc.p and scc.pr) so it will be able to receive any kind of parameter?

Comment: `()` is missing. `double b=scc.id;` should be `double b=scc.id();`.

Comment: `is`, `id` and `ii` are methods, not variables.

Comment: These comments should really be answers.  A good comment would be something like this:  "Why would you ever want to make your code this hard to read?"

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: @Roman C - The OP says, "*I just started learning Java*"

Comment: @Lion That's what I'm trying to get what did he learn in Java. Such a term *shortcut* is new to me. Could you explain?

Comment: I also forget that shortcut is a keyboard key code that makes a hotkey menu items available. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
String a=scc.is;
double b=scc.id;
int c=scc.ii;
```

... you're trying to refer to *methods* as if they were *variables*. You need to call the methods:

```
String a=scc.is();
double b=scc.id();
int c=scc.ii();
```

As a side-note, I would *strongly* discourage you from doing all of this to start with. Even if you want a convenience class, please give the methods sensible names - `writeInt`, `readInt` etc. Using abbreviations like this makes the code very hard to read.

Comment: Actually it's 7377 more than that. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
the thing is, i ran into another problem... please read the the Extra part i just wrote there... thanks in ahead!

Comment: @user1857509: Well it sounds like you want overloads for `print` to take `double` and `float` parameters...

Comment: ummm.... New to Java... Overloads? whats that and how do I do that?
Thanks in ahead!

Comment: @user1857509: Did you try searching before asking? If you're new to Java, you should be learning from a book or well-structured tutorial - did you see what that had to say about overoading?

Comment: @JonSkeet
Searched for it and found an answer! thanks! now i made the shortcuts a bit more read-able, called the print "print" instead of p and such. now another question, and it will probably be the last: I made the print so that everything i will write will be accepted (String, int, double) now can I do the same with the input? Since it has no parameters required it just won't work because "Input" is allready defined and such... Thanks in ahead! –

Answer (score 1):

Thats because "is" is a method and you are attempting to access it as a public variable.

Try:

```
String a = scc.is();
```

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
String a=scc.is;
double b=scc.id;
```

the () are missing:

correct woul dbe:

```
String a=scc.is();
double b=scc.id();
```

Further Tipp: Please remove the short cuts, that code is less readable